# .Net core container app showing No webpage was found for the web address: https://xyzapp.azurewebsites.net/

Tags: .net, docker, asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-appservice

I am running .NET Core API on docker and it's working fine on my local machine as I create Azure devops pipelines it is not working on Azure app service showing error

No webpage was found for the web address: https://xyzapp.azurewebsites.net/swagger/index.html
HTTP ERROR 404

When I build the image locally and push it to Azure app service using the same dockerfile it is then working fine.

Here are the error logs of api

*08:45:46 WRN] Failed to determine the https port for redirect.*
*[08:45:46 INF] HTTP GET / responded 404 in 162.0077 ms*

Does anyone has idea what's wrong in it, locally build is running and by building Azure devops showing this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test your webapi directly by postman or browser, it should be working fine.

And if your all steps in devops is correct, then you need check your Program.cs file (.Net6). If you are using other version, you need check Startup.cs file.

Then find the `IsDevelopment` condition, something like below.

```
if(app.Environment.IsDevelopment){
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
```

Change it to

```
if(app.Environment.IsDevelopment){
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}else{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
```

I think that swagger is generally used for project cooperation or in development mode. The `/swagger/index.html` page is generally not provided in the production environment, which should be for security.